# In the spark mllib, how to set L2 regular param in LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I want to use L2 regularizers and set L2 regular param in LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, but there is no example in mllib's programming guides.So anyone please tell me how to use L2 regularizers in LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, my colleagues told me how to solve this problem. I show the answer and maybe help some people with the same problems I encountered.

```
val paramL2: Double = 0.05  //  L2 regularization coefficient
val logisticRegressionWithLBFGS = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
logisticRegressionWithLBFGS.optimizer.setRegParam(paramL2)  // set L2 regularization coefficient
logisticRegressionWithLBFGS.setIntercept(true).setNumClasses(15)
val model = logisticRegressionWithLBFGS.run(trainingSamples)  // train model use some training samples
```

If you encounter a similar problem, we'd better look at the mllib source code and you can find answer. Just some suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Spark's `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` returns a regularized model estimate.

Standard feature scaling and L2 regularization are used by default in [`LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.html).

It is answered for similar question [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/5712/19274).